# Create Row Number Column by Two Columns SAS

Tags: sas

I want to add a row number column to a SAS data set based on the values of two columns.

Type_1 and Type_2 columns are what I have and the Row Number is what I need.

```
Type_1  Type_2  Row Number
A       1       1
A       1       2
A       2       1
A       2       2
B       1       1
B       2       1
B       2       2
B       3       1
C       1       1
C       1       2
C       2       1
C       3       1
C       4       1
C       4       2
```

I have this code to count rows on one column value:

```
data work.want;
set work.have;
rownumber + 1;
by type_1 notsorted;
if first.type_1 then rownumber=1;
run;
```

But I don't know how to scale this to being able to group by multiple column criteria.  I know that I can just concatenate `type_1` and `type_2` and the above code would work, but I would like to be able to do it without making a helper column.  Is there any way to change the data step for it to work?  Or is there another SAS function that I don't know of that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reset it on any change in either TYPE_1 or TYPE_2, then just use the last variable in the list; any change in an earlier variable will trigger a change in the `FIRST` variable.

```
data work.want;
  set work.have;
  by type_1 type_2 notsorted;
  rownumber + 1;
  if first.type_2 then rownumber=1;
run;
```